# Using fields in inherited bound data

Tags: d3.js

I am attempting to get my head around using bound data with d3.js. I'm following the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) and am now a little confused.

I want to produce donut charts with radii that vary depending on the data. I am comfortable producing the arcs to make up a donut using an array, but am having a hard time working out how to pass along a size parameter with the data binding of the arc. For example, if the data bound to the parent of the arc is something like `{size: 20, cont: [1, 7]}`, how can I bind the first element of the array *as well* as the size element? I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9dMx/1/) attempting to show what I am talking about. In that example, the two donuts should be different sizes. I have commented out the kind of thing I suspect should be going on on line 14.

I have tried variations on:

```
var arcs = donuts.selectAll(".arc")
           .data(function(d) { var temp = [];
                    temp.push(d.cont);
                    temp.push(d.size);
                    return temp; })
           .enter()
           .append("g")
           .attr("class", "arc");
```

But it is clearly not producing what I expect.

Comment: innerRadius will always same  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't really the data inheritance, but the fact that you're passing the original data to a layout and then only the result of that to your drawing functions. The pie layout does store the original datum in the `.data` member of the result, but you're only passing it part of the original data.

The "proper" thing to do would be to refactor your data structure such that you can pass it in as-is and use the pie layout's `.value()` function to tell it how to access the data. Then you can directly access the original data.

There's however a quicker solution -- you can simply use the indices that are passed to your function to index into the original array. The code for this would look like this.

```
.attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.outerRadius(dataset[j].size)(d); })
```

Note that you need two indices here because you have nested data -- `i` would be the index within your array of values for a single pie chart, whereas `j` denotes the index of the element at the level above that. Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W9dMx/3/).

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. Sorry about the delay, I've been out of action. Can you recommend a good source to have a crack at the 'proper' way? (refactoring) or even if there is an example of what 'shape' the data should be in? thanks

Comment: I would use a nested array that, at the bottom level, has an element for each value in `cont` that contains the other data as well. At the level above, you would need to nest by `name`. I'm sure there are other ways though.